# DiscordJS, reply to certain userID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

I want bot to reply only certain user so I wrote this code but it doesn't work. Can you help me about it?

```
const userID = '322032528460611604'

client.on("message", function(message) {
    if(!message.sender === userID) message.channel.send('Hello there!')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I use `message.author.id` in my bot and it works just fine.**

```
const userID = '322032528460611604'

client.on("message", function(message) {
    if(message.author.id === userID) 
        return message.channel.send('Hello there!')
    });
```

Comment: thanks. it solved the issue. i appreciated it